# PyQt5 - How to insert windows command result into qlabel

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am first time to learning PyQt5 and I am puzzled by qlabel
The windows 10 cmd "wmic cpu get name" will return current CPU name.
(e.g: Name Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz)
I want put this result into qlabel.
which Public Functions or slots suit for this result?
Thanks

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import xxxx_UI as ui
import subprocess,os,sys

class Main(QMainWindow, ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.setupUi(self)
         self.Exit_BTN.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
         Processor_content=os.system("wmic cpu get name")
         self.processor_content.settext(self.processor_content)
    def buttonClicked(self):
        window.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It should be `self.processor_content.setText(Processor_content)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: Do not use os.system() since it does not return the result, in the duplicate it indicates how to obtain the output of a command in python

Answer (score 0):

`os.system()` will not return you the actual output, it will send it to the interpreter's console.

```
>>Processor_content=os.system("wmic cpu get name")
```

If you want to get the output into a variable, you should use `subprocess.check_output()`
You can do the following:

```
>>Processor_content = subprocess.check_output("wmic cpu get name")
```

But it gives you the byte string as you can see in the following output:

```
>>Processor_content
b'Name                                      \r\r\nIntel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz  \r\r\n\r\r\n'
```

Since, it is a bytestring, you may want to decode it:

```
>>Processor_content.decode('ascii')
'Name                                      \r\r\nIntel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz  \r\r\n\r\r\n'
```

If you want, slightly process this string to make it look better, something like this:

```
>>Processor_content = Processor_content.decode('ascii').replace('Name', '').strip()
>>Processor_content
'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz'
```

Now finally, you can use this string to show in the `Qt`:

```
 self.processor_content.setText(Processor_content)
```

Comment: I don't think that the question was *How to extract the cpu name from the command result*

Comment: Ya But he is trying to set the label with whatever output `os.system()` gives, but `os.system()` is going to pass the output to the interpreter's console, not the variable. And until you have the value you are trying to display, how can you proceed further?

Comment: You're right, but if that's the case I suggest you also edit the question to match the answer

Comment: I don't think I need to, read the post once, *The windows 10 cmd "wmic cpu get name" will return current CPU name. (e.g: Name Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz) I want put this result into qlabel*

Comment: Exactly. By reading the post I understand that the question is about QLabel, not the processor name

Comment: Good for you may be

Comment: I don't think your answer should be downvoted, but as I said, you should edit the question. Maybe you're right and the meaning is clear, but then it should have different tags

Comment: Because the issue it not related to Qt and it should be marked as a duplicate of questions already answered

Comment: Also, it's `setText()`